# Rails links not connecting properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, hyperlink

I am a rails beginner and I have created 3 models/controllers/views using `rails generate scaffold`:

- Subjects, which have many topics
- Topics, which have many notes
- Notes

When I go to `http://localhost:3000/subjects/1/topics`, Rails lists the empty list of topics and when the 'New Topic' link is clicked, you are taken to `http://localhost:3000/topics/new`.

Should and how do I get the link for 'New Topic' to take the user to `http://localhost:3000/subjects/:id/topics/new` instead of `http://localhost:3000/topics/new` and should the new topic form submit to `http://localhost:3000/subjects/:id/topics/new` instead of `http://localhost:3000/topics`?

**views/topics/index:**

```
<h1>Listing topics</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @topics.each do |topic| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= topic.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', topic %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_topic_path(topic) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', topic, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Topic', new_topic_path %>
```

**controllers/topics:**

```
def new
  @topic = Topic.new

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @topic }
  end
end

def edit
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
end

def create
  @topic = Topic.new(params[:topic])
  @topic.subject_id = params[:project_id]
  respond_to do |format|
    if @topic.save
      format.html { redirect_to subject_path(@topic.subject_id), notice: 'Topic was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @topic, status: :created, location: @topic }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @topic.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**new topics form:**

```
<%= form_for(@topic) do |f| %>
  <% if @topic.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@topic.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this topic from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @topic.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**routes:**

```
resources :subjects do
  resources :topics do
    resources :notes
  end
end

resources :notes


resources :topics


resources :subjects

root :to => 'subjects#index'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you go to `http://localhost:3000/subjects/1/topics` the action `index` of controller `TopicsController` is called with the `params[:subject_id]` set to `1`.

So in your controller action, you have to check for this parameter and filter the topics if it is given

```
def index
  if params[:subject_id].present?
    @subject=Subject.find params[:subject_id]
    @topics=@subject.topics
  else
    @topics=Topic.all
  end
end
```

and in your index view, you have to use this url, if @subject ist present:

```
<%= link_to 'New Topic', @subject.present? ? new_subject_topic_path(@subject) : new_topic_path %>
```

in your topics new action again you get the `:subject_id` as a parameter:

```
def new
  @subject=Subject.find params[:subject_id]
  @topic = @subject.topics.new
end
```

then in your topics form, you can forward the `subject_id` in a hidden field:

```
<%= form_for(@topic) do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.hidden_field :subject_id %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

The rest of your TobicsController can stay the same. The Topic is assiciated to the Subject by the `subject_id`

Answer (score 0):

Once you have declared the nested resources, don't declare those resources again.

Deep nesting of resources is not recommended. You should think about doing shallow nesting, and you can read about this in the [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html).

> One way to avoid deep nesting (as recommended above) is to generate
>   the collection actions scoped under the parent, so as to get a sense
>   of the hierarchy, but to not nest the member actions. In other words,
>   to only build routes with the minimal amount of information to
>   uniquely identify the resource, like this:

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments, only: [:index, :new, :create]
end
resources :comments, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

> This idea strikes a balance between descriptive routes and deep
>   nesting.

Comment: I had to declare my resources twice because I would have problems with link urls which were undeclared, however I will change this and take out the deep nesting.